# Similar behavior to innerText but preserving <img> tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to get the inner text of elements but ideally keeping any image tags they contain intact.
So the following:

```
<span>some<img src="first"><b>awesome</b><span>text<img src="second"></span></span>
```

should be converted to something like:

```
some<img src="first">awesometext<img src="second">
```

Any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a simple way. As you want to strip all nodes but imgs and text nodes, you will have to cycle the childnodes. Here an example native js code:

```js
function cleaned(node) {
  if (node.nodeType === node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return node.data;
  } else if (node.tagName === "IMG") {
    return node.outerHTML;
  } else {
    var ret = "";
    if (!node.childNodes) {
      return ret;
    }
    node.childNodes.forEach(function(subnode) {
      ret += cleaned(subnode);
    });
    return ret;
  }
}

var str = cleaned(document.getElementById("src"));

console.info(str);
```

```html
<div id="src">
  <span>some<img src="first"><b>awesome</b><span>text<img src="second"></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Joschi's answer, I generalized the function so that it can accept a selector of elements the user needs to keep intact:

```
function stringifyNodeExcept(node, exceptSelector) {
    const matchesSelector = node.matches || node.webkitMatchesSelector || node.mozMatchesSelector || node.msMatchesSelector;

    if (node.nodeType === node.TEXT_NODE) {
        return node.data;
    } else if (matchesSelector.call(node, exceptSelector)) {
        return node.outerHTML;
    } else {
        var ret = "";
        if (!node.childNodes) {
            return ret;
        }
        node.childNodes.forEach(function (subnode) {
            ret += stringifyNodeExcept(subnode, exceptSelector);
        });
        return ret;
    }
}
```